# SQLite with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlite

Is there any good sample ASP.NET MVC web application that uses SQLite? I thought of studying SQLite with ASP.NET. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SQLite uses the same provider model as ADO.NET. So pick any tutorial you like about SQL Server and replace `SqlConnection` with `SQLiteConnection`. I wrote a [sample application](http://github.com/darind/samplemvc) using FluentNHibernate with SQLite you may take a look at.

Or if you don't use an ORM, simply declare a method in your repository and you are good to go:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetIds()
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(SomeConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man its always nice to get reply from you... I ll check it out...